# reading a specific column in .txt file ??? i need to run a specific column

Tags: java, split, row, text-files, identity-column

Text file content as follows:

```
**Name  class Section School**  
tin    10     a        ysr 
cane    9     a        cik
morj    8     b        vit
vel     7     d        klm
```

Comment: does conversion of txt to csv via external tool is an option for you ? And then read the csv in java...

Comment: Please write text input in code format to be easier to read.

Comment: You can split line by space and get the column that you want.

Comment: You can use regular expressions. Could you give an example.What you need to match.

Comment: can u provide me the code to solve???????

Comment: I need to get "Section " column  as output. can u provide me the code???

Answer (score 0):

this solution is working with the input that you have provided, but this is a shortcut solution. Is this solution good enough for you, or do you want a better solution?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FIrst {
      public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
      { 

      File file = new File("data.txt"); 

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

      String st; 

      String[] columnNames = null;
      if ((st = br.readLine()) == null) {
          System.out.println("did not find first line");
          return;
      }

      while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(st.split(" ")[3]);
      } 
}
```

Comment: Hi CrazyArtist this is a shortcut and working solution....
do you want some other solution or is this solution working fine for you?